# If column A is null then use column B. If column B is null then use column C

Tags: ms-access, iif-function

I am using MS Access.

I want to create an IIF expression where if Column A is null use column B. If column B is blank, use column C.

I have gotten this so far and it doesn't seem to work

```
IIf(IsNull([DataTable]![State1]),[DataTable]![State2],
IIf(IsNull([DataTable]![State2]),[DataTable]![State3],
IIf(IsNull([DataTable]![State3]),[DataTable]![State4])))
```

I am not an advanced user of Access and am not sure why this is not working for me.

Comment: Yes, its an expression I tried to create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Switch Function](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) to express the logic you want.

This is the output from the query below.  The first 5 columns are contained in *DataTable*, and the final column is produced by the `Switch` expression.

```sql
id State1 State2 State3 State4 computed_column
-- ------ ------ ------ ------ ---------------
 1                           a               a
 2                    b                      b
 3             c                             c
 4      d                                    d
 5                                    all Null

SELECT
    d.id,
    d.State1,
    d.State2,
    d.State3,
    d.State4,
    Switch(
        d.State1 Is Not Null, d.State1,
        d.State2 Is Not Null, d.State2,
        d.State3 Is Not Null, d.State3,
        d.State4 Is Not Null, d.State4,
        True, 'all Null'
    ) AS computed_column
FROM DataTable AS d;
```

Alternatively, if you will be running your query from within an Access session, you can use nested [Nz Functions](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c).  This query produces the same result as above.

```sql
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.State1,
    d.State2,
    d.State3,
    d.State4,
    Nz(d.State1,
        Nz(d.State2,
        Nz(d.State3,
        Nz(d.State4,
        'all Null')))
    ) AS computed_column
FROM DataTable AS d;
```